# Jenkins Helm backup fails with WebIdentityErr

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I have Jenkins running in an AWS EKS cluster. It was deployed using the helm chart available at [jenkinsci/jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/jenkins). I want to use the backup option that is included in the helm chart. My configuration for backup looks like:

```
backup:
  enabled: true
  schedule: "* 04 * * *"
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: "arn:aws:iam::221100446688:role/jenkins-backup"
  image:
    repository: "maorfr/kube-tasks"
    tag: "0.2.0"
  destination: "s3://my-jenkins-tings/backup"
```

I'm getting this error:

```
2020/09/27 05:08:56 Backup started!
2020/09/27 05:08:56 Getting clients
2020/09/27 05:08:59 WebIdentityErr: unable to read file at /var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token
caused by: open /var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token: permission denied
```

I have tried adding fsUser & Group, even updating the annotation for the `jenkins-backup` service account. Still the same error.

Comment: what's eks version? What are file permissions? does jenkins container run under root user?

Comment: eks version 1.16.13
file perms is read for the jenkins UID user...  
jenkins runs under jenkins UID fsUser & Group are set to 1000.

Comment: This is completely unrelated to your question, but FWIW, even if you solve this error, you may run into this issue:  https://github.com/nuvo/kube-tasks/issues/6
We were also using the backup option with the helm chart, and due to this issue with kube-tasks, the backup simply stopped working with S3.  We ended up ditching the helm-based backup option.  Just a heads-up

Comment: @Tom what approach did you end up going with?

Comment: I added a job to run on the master node that zips up the Jenkins home directory and uses ‘aws s3 cp’ to send it to an s3 bucket.  The job was much faster (minutes instead of hours)